How to properly handle hypothesis testing in the case of no rejection
I am learning about hypothesis testing and am wondering how to properly test a hypothesis in the following case. I am rather new to the platform, please let me know if I made a mistake in my question (related to the content or not)
Suppose I have the random variables $X$ ~ $N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $X$ ~ $N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$, and want to test whether $\mu_x$ is bigger than $\mu_y$. I create the following hypothesis:
H0: $\mu_x \leq \mu_y$
H1: $\mu_x > \mu_y$
I conduct my experiment (the first time) with a certain test-size $\alpha$. I find that using this data, I can not reject H0. I conclude this experiment by saying that I do not have enough results to find that $\mu_x > \mu_y$.
Now suppose I want to follow up this experiment and want to check, based on this test result, if the opposite is true: I want to test whether $\mu_x$ is smaller than $\mu_y$. I now create the following hypothesis:
H0: $\mu_x \geq \mu_y$
H1: $\mu_x < \mu_y$
I conduct my experiment (the second time) with the same test-size $\alpha$. I use this data and find that under this constraint, I can reject H0. I conclude this experiment by saying that there are significant results that indicate $\mu_x < \mu_y$.
It was explained to me that reusing the same data is not allowed: this is a form of data snooping. I am now wondering, considering that we do not use the same data but only the same model: Is this a correct conduction and conclusion of the experiment, especially considering the constraint of the test-size $\alpha$? In other words: would the probability of making a type-1 error still be $\alpha$?
The reason for my confusion is due to the fact that we could alternatively, at the start, take the hypothesis:
H0: $\mu_x = \mu_y$
H1: $\mu_x \neq \mu_y$
And conduct the experiment. Then we now obtain a test size of $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ per tail if we consider the same total test size as before, meaning if we would compare the critical regions for both this test and the previous two, it would require data that is more "extreme" to reject H0 for the two-tailed test, but it can reject in both directions.
This makes it seem like it is easier to find significant results which lead to the rejection of H0 if we use the one-tailed approach instead of the two-tailed approach, but perhaps this is helped by taking a second experiment and by the fact that there is only rejection in one direction.
Thanks in advance for any help!
